# Please help me better understand this one "except"conditional line

Tags: python, indexing, try-catch, except, operations

I'm about a couple weeks into learning Python.

With the guidance of user:' Lost' here on Stackoverflow I was able to figure out how to build a simple decoder program. He suggested a code and I changed a few things but what was important for me was that I understood what was happening. I understand 97% of this code except for the `except: i += 1` line in the `decode()`. As of now the code works, but I want to understand that line.

So basically this code unscrambles an encrypted word based on a specific criteria. You can enter this sample encrypted word to try it out. `"0C1gA2uiT3hj3S"` the answer should be `"CATS"`

I tried replacing the except: `i += 1` with a Value Error because I have never seen a Try/Except conditional that just had an operational and no Error clause. But replacing it with Value Error created a never ending loop.

My question is what is the purpose of writing the except: `i += 1` as it is.

'Lost' if you're there could you answer this question. Sorry, about the old thread

```
def unscramble(elist):

    answer = []
    i = 0

    while i <= len(elist):

        try:
            if int(elist[i]) > -1:
                i = i + int(elist[i]) + 1
                answer.append(elist[i])
        except:
            i += 1

    return "".join(answer)

def boom():
    eword  = input("paste in your encrypted message here >> ")
    elist = list(eword)
    answer = unscramble(elist)
    print (answer)

clear()
boom()
```

Comment: That isn't good code, I suggest you find something else to learn from.

Comment: Start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to advance `i` by one, skipping the current character in case the cast to `int` fails, i.e. if `elist[i]` is not a digit.

Comment: Thanks wonce! Everyone is really helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors, than can occur inside the try-Block:

1. `i` is out of index, because the while loop runs one index to far.
2. `elist[i]` is not a number, which leads to an ValueError
3. `i = i + int(elist[i]) + 1` gets to big, and the next index access leads also to an IndexError

In either way, the except-clause will ignore the next character. And the loop goes on.

An correct implementation wouldn't need any exceptions:

```
def unscramble(elist):
    answer = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(elist):
        i += int(elist[i]) + 1
        answer.append(elist[i])
        i += 1
    return "".join(answer)
```

Comment: I see Daniel! Thank you. Your code is much cleaner.

Comment: The code is not equivalent however. The original code will unscramble "0CX1gA2uiT3hj3S" into "CATS", this one will throw an error.